# R concatenating two factors

Tags: r

This is making me feel dumb, but I am trying to produce a single vector/df/list/etc (anything but a matrix) concatenating two factors.  Here's the scenario.  I have a 100k line dataset.  I used the top half to predict the bottom half and vice versa using `knn`.  So now I have 2 objects created by `knn predict()`.

```
> head(pred11)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
Levels: 0 1
> head(pred12)
[1] 0 1 1 0 0 0
Levels: 0 1
> class(pred11)
[1] "factor"
> class(pred12)
[1] "factor"
```

Here's where my problem starts:

```
> pred13 <- rbind(pred11, pred12)
> class(pred13)
[1] "matrix"
```

There are 2 problems.  First it changes the 0's and 1's to 1's and 2's and second it seems to create a huge matrix that's eats all my memory.  I've tried messing with `as.numeric()`, `data.frame()`, etc, but can't get it to just combine the 2 50k factors into 1 100k one.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The title and description confused me - it seemed like you need an [*interaction*](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-November/178808.html) (see ?interaction) of factors, but in fact you need *concatenation*. "Combination" is rather ambigous term. I will try to edit your question to make this clear.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`rbind` will create 2 x 50000 matrix in your case which isn't what you want. `c` is the correct function to combine 2 vectors in a single longer vector. When you use `rbind` or `c` on a factor, it will use the underlying integers that map to the levels. In general you need to combine as a character before refactoring:

```
x1 <- factor(sample(0:1,10,replace=T))
x2 <- factor(sample(0:1,10,replace=T))

factor(c(as.character(x1),as.character(x2)))
 [1] 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
Levels: 0 1
```

Answer (score 29):

@James presented one way, I'll chip in with another (shorter):

```
set.seed(42)
x1 <- factor(sample(0:1,10,replace=T))
x2 <- factor(sample(0:1,10,replace=T))

unlist(list(x1,x2))
# [1] 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
#Levels: 0 1
```

...This might seem a bit like magic, but `unlist` has special support for factors for this particular purpose! All elements in the list must be factors for this to work.

Comment: +1000 for the Tommy's answer, it allows to avoid using `as.character` and when working with factors, this is __VERY__ pleasant